# Redshift Correlated Subquery error internal

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a query in MYSQL which count `products` from specific vendor with `product_status` like `Live, Pause, soldout, Partial-Soldout` etc. Query include Subquery but works perfect in Mysql. For Redshift (Postgre v8.x) it gives error `correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error`

**Query (POSTGRES)**

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN (vendor_id = 6 AND status = 1) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "vex",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN (vendor_id = 6 AND status = 1 AND p.p_id IN (SELECT pov.p_id FROM product_option_value pov WHERE pov.p_id AND p.quantity != pov.quantity AND pov.quantity = 0 GROUP BY pov.p_id)) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "vex-Partial-Soldout",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN (vendor_id = 6 AND status = 1 AND p.quantity = 0) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "vex-Soldout",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN (vendor_id = 5 AND status = 1) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "vey-DXB",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN (vendor_id = 5 AND status = 1 AND p.p_id IN (SELECT pov.p_id FROM product_option_value pov WHERE pov._id AND p.quantity != pov.quantity AND pov.quantity = 0 GROUP BY pov.p_id)) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "vey-Partial-Soldout",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN (vendor_id = 5 AND status = 1 AND p.quantity = 0) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "vey-Soldout"
FROM product p
```

**Table Structure**

```
//Product p table
*  p_id *   model   *   vendor_id   *   status  * Quantity * 
* 1001  *   HB1     *      1        *   1       *  10      *
* 1002  *   HB2     *      6        *   1       *  17      *
* 1003  *   HB3     *      5        *   1       *  19      *
* 1004  *   HB4     *      2        *   1       *  3       *
* 1005  *   HB5     *      1        *   1       *  8       *
* 1006  *   HB6     *      6        *   1       *  55      *
* 1007  *   HB7     *      3        *   1       *  32      *
* 1008  *   HB8     *      5        *   1       *  6       *
* 1009  *   HB9     *      5        *   1       *  10      *


//product_option_value pov table
*   pov_id  *   p_id    *   opt_id    *   quantity   * 
*   1       *   1001    *   11        *   10         *
*   2       *   1002    *   11        *   17         *
*   3       *   1003    *   11        *   0          *
*   4       *   1004    *   11        *   3          *
*   5       *   1005    *   11        *   8          *
*   6       *   1006    *   11        *   0          *
*   7       *   1007    *   11        *   32         *
*   8       *   1008    *   11        *   6          *
*   9       *   1009    *   11        *   0          *
```

`Group by` is necessary in subquery so left join is also not solving the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Narrow the query to one column in the SELECT clause and than narrow the expression until you'll find the specific element that causes the issue

Comment: FYI, putting `SELECT` statements within Select lines is a very inefficient way to write SQL queries. It effectively needs to run a query for every row of the outer query. You can probably rewrite it to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, then test whether the joined column is `NULL`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein , i am big fan of you ..i followed many answers of you... i tried `LEFT JOIN` but query needs to be GROUP BY product id

Comment: You can do a LEFT OUTER JOIN to a query (including the GROUP BY).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i tried LEFT OUTER JOIN but still not getting result... Actully, in mysql,  Subquery SELECT statement return an array of `p_id` which is used for `IN` function at `vex-Partial-Soldout`  line...

Comment: @MuhammadHashirAnwaar would you mind letting us know if the answers worked?

Answer (score 0):

The logic in the subqueries in quite painful to follow, so I'm not sure I have it 100% correct.  For instance, the sample data only seems to have one row per product, but I don't know if that is really the case.  Or what `opt_id` is, because that would seem to be useful in a query that uses the `pov` table.

That said, it appears that you just need `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to get what you want -- a query that is much simpler and should be faster in any database.

In the following query, I have also split the two vendors on different rows.  That is at least helpful to get the logic correct:

```
SELECT vendor_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT p.p_id) AS num_products,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.quantity <> pov.quantity AND pov.quantity = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as partial_soldout,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN p.quantity = 0 THEN p.p_id END) as soldout
FROM product p LEFT JOIN
     product_option_value pov
     ON pov.p_id = p.p_pid
WHERE p.vendor_id IN (5, 6) AND p.status = 1
GROUP BY p.vendor_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the "pov.p_id AND" just after the where clause from the two expressions which calculate  "vex-Partial-Soldout" and "vey-Partial-Soldout". Then it is working on postgreSQL9.6 and output is matching with your sqlserver version output.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN (vendor_id = 6 AND status = 1) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "vex",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN (vendor_id = 6 AND status = 1 AND p.p_id IN (SELECT pov.p_id FROM product_option_value pov WHERE p.quantity != pov.quantity AND pov.quantity = 0 GROUP BY pov.p_id)) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "vex-Partial-Soldout",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN (vendor_id = 6 AND status = 1 AND p.quantity = 0) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "vex-Soldout",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN (vendor_id = 5 AND status = 1) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "vey-DXB",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN (vendor_id = 5 AND status = 1 AND p.p_id IN (SELECT pov.p_id FROM product_option_value pov WHERE p.quantity != pov.quantity AND pov.quantity = 0 GROUP BY pov.p_id)) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "vey-Partial-Soldout",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN (vendor_id = 5 AND status = 1 AND p.quantity = 0) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "vey-Soldout"
FROM product p
```

Note: I did not paid much attention to your logic, as a best practice please avoid writing select statements within your select.